# edit post is not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am learning Cakephp framwork. I am having problem while I am trying to update database record.

This is Controller code for edit post....

```
$this->loadModel('Post');
            if($this->request->is('put')):
            $this->Post->id = $this->params['id'];
            if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)):
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Page has been edited'));
                    $this->redirect('/User/index');
                endif;
            else:
            $this->set('postinfo', $this->Post->findById($this->params['id']));
            endif;
        }
```

This is view/edit.ctp file

```
echo $this->Form->update('Post', array(
    'method' => 'put'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('title',array('type' => 'text','value'=>$postinfo['Post']['title']));
    echo $this->Form->input('body', array('type' => 'textarea','value' => $postinfo['Post']['body']));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Submit', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
```

But this code does not update record in database...I tried everything from book.cakephp.org tutorial and other tutorials related to cakephp..
I hope I'll get some help from you guys :)

Comment: `$this->Form->update` is a function that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If this is PostController, than you don't need to call the $this->loadModel('Post'); function.

In view you need a hidden field with id of post.

Comment: I recommend you, that you go trough Cookbook blog tutorial.

Comment: If I remove $this->loadModel('Post') from controller error shows that unable to call non-member findById(), so that I am using loadModel function

Comment: And I tried with that hidden id field in view , but still its not working :(

Comment: I have mentioned code related to edit from controller and view, that's all what i have about edit function

Comment: To view add echo $this->Form->input('id');

In controller change this line 
$this->set('postinfo', $this->Post->findById($this->params['id'])); with
$this->request->data = $this->Post->findById($this->params['id']);

Answer (score 0):

Controller code for edit post

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

   $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
         $this->Post->id = $id;

        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been updated.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } 
    else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to update your post.');
        }
    }

    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $post;
    }
}


view/edit.ctp file 

<h1>Edit Post</h1>
  <?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Post');
    echo $this->Form->input('title');
    echo $this->Form->input('body', array('rows' => '3'));
    echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>
```